# Can I use Spring Framework 4.3.x + Spring Data MongoDB 2.1.x + MongoRepository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb

I have a project which works  with Spring Framework 4.3.30.RELEASE I want to connect to mongodb via Spring Data MongoDB and use MongoRepository to have access to the pieces data

```
<!-- Mongodb + Spring data mongodb -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.21.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.11</version>
</dependency>
```

I have a model

```
@Document(collection = "order")
public class Order {
    @Id
    private String id;
    priavte String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

I've created repository

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface OrderRepository extends MongoRepository<Order, String> {
}
```

That's my configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "ua.home.repository")
public class MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb://localhost:27017/dev");
        MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .build();

        return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "dev";
    }

    @Override
    protected Collection<String> getMappingBasePackages() {
        return Collections.singleton("ua.home.model");
    }
}
```

But I've got the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.ReactiveTypeDescriptor
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass (SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass (ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass (ClassRealm.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass (WebAppClassLoader.java:565)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.findDescriptor (ReactiveWrappers.java:281)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.isNoValueType (ReactiveWrappers.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.isWrapper (ReactiveWrappers.java:268)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.supports (ReactiveWrappers.java:158)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$1MatchSink.accept (MatchOps.java:90)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.forEachRemaining (Streams.java:419)
    at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining (Streams.java:742)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach (ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept (ReferencePipeline.java:270)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance (Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel (ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel (AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto (AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential (MatchOps.java:230)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential (MatchOps.java:196)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate (AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch (ReferencePipeline.java:449)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.usesReactiveType (ReactiveWrappers.java:173)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractRepositoryMetadata.isReactiveRepository (AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java:129)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.MongoRepositoryConfigurationExtension.useRepositoryConfiguration (MongoRepositoryConfigurationExtension.java:147)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations (RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:107)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn (RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:148)
```

I've figured out that a class `org.springframework.core.ReactiveTypeDescriptor` is from Spring 5
I need an advice Should I get earlier version of spring-data-mongodb? Can I override `AbstractRepositoryMetadata` some how to have my own `isReactiveRepository` method? Other options?

Comment: In short no. Minimum is Spring 5.1 which is what is being used to build it, so it expects the api's etc. to be available. You can probably work around this error (slightly) to run into the next, and the next and the next. I would strongly suggest to upgrade to Spring 5.3 as that is still maintained, Spring 4.3 hasn't been maintained for a long time.

Comment: @M.Deinum Updating spring framework version is not an option :(
Much easier to downgrade version of spring data.

But I thought that Spring Framework 4.3.x and Spring Data MongoDB 2.1.x are compatible. Isn't it?

Comment: No it isn't as it requires Spring 5.1 at a minimum, the error you get is already a hinting at that.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for you answers. Do you know how to find a version of spring data mongodb which can be compatible with Spring Framework 4.3.x?

Comment: The compatibility is mentioned in the documentation. Why wouldn't an upgrade be an option? You are using an ancient version of Spring and generally it is a drop in replacement.

Comment: I've found out that I need to use a version 1.10.23.RELEASE of spring data mongodb.
@M.Deinum It's not easy to upgrade Spring Framework version in my case. Migration from Spring 3 to Spring 4 took a couple months

Comment: Then delaying the upgrade will only make it longer, if it hurts do it more often (i.e. keep tracking the latest release). However I do believe that upgrading from 4.3 to the 5.x line (do small steps move from 4.3 to 5.0.x then 5.1.x etc. fix little things that might break). I doubt it will take months. Staying back in the past will only make things worse.